# A proof about measurable space

Tags: measure-theory

If $(E,X)$ be a measurable space, $D\in X$, and $ (D,M)$ be the trace of $(E,X)$ on $D$. Let $\mu$ be a measure on $(D,M)$ and define $v$ by $v(A) = \mu(A \cap D), A \in X$.

Show the fact that $v$ is a measure on$(E,X)$.

Answer (score 1):

First notice that $A \cap D \in M$ for $A \in X$ so $\nu$ is well-defined. Obviously $\nu \geq 0$ since $\mu \geq 0$.

Let's check that $\nu(\emptyset) = 0$:
$$\nu(\emptyset) = \mu(\emptyset \cap D) = \mu(\emptyset) = 0$$

To check $\sigma$-additivity of $\nu$, let $(A_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of pairwise disjoint sets in $X$. Then $(A_n \cap D)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of pairwise disjoint sets in $M$ so by $\sigma-$additivity of $\mu$ we have:

$$\nu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right) = \mu\left(\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right) \cap D\right) = \mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (A_n \cap D)\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_n \cap D) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \nu(A_n)$$

Hence, $\nu$ is a measure on $(E, X)$.